# select first item of a collection that satisfies given predicate in clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there a function in clojure that (given a predicate and a collection),
selects the first item that satisfies the given predicate and stop the iteration?

for example:

```
(select-first #(> % 10) (range))
=> 11
```

If not, maybe someone could hint me about an idiomatic implementation

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities.

**`some`**

`some` returns the first non-nil value its predicate returns.

```
(some #(when (> % 10) %) (range)) ;; => 11
```

**`filter` + `first`**

`filter` retains those elements that match a predicate, `first` retrieves the first of them.

```
(first (filter #(> % 10) (range))) ;; => 11
```

**`remove` + `first`**

If you want to find the first element that does *not* match your predicate, `remove` is your friend:

```
(first (remove #(<= % 10) (range))) ;; => 11
```

Or with `some`:

```
(some #(when-not (<= % 10) %) (range)) ;; => 11
```

So, that's it, I guess.

Comment: glad i could help! (although the other answer was posted about 20secs before mine)

Comment: A caveat -- `(first (filter ...))` is more strict (and fast, since filter returns a lazy sequence) because using `some` is ambiguous -- consider `(some #(when (nil? %)  %)`. Using `some` will find the first *non-nil* element.

Comment: @djhaskin987 It's true that if you're using `some` to find a `nil` element you'll traverse the whole sequence (and thus potentially never terminate) - in other cases it will only realize lazy seqs as far as it needs to. Note, however, that my description of `some` already contains the _non-nil_ part you emphasize. :)

Answer (score 8):

Use filter and first

```
user=> (->> (range) (filter #(> % 10)) first)
11
user=> (first (filter #(> % 10) (range)))
11
```

Comment: without lazy evaluation isn't this inefficient?

Comment: @JosephGarvin sure, range and filter are lazy. Without lazy evaluation range will take infinite time.